# struggle with finding convergence for this integral. Any advice?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int _0^{\infty \:}\:\frac{\left(x^{\frac{1}{4}}+1\right)\cdot \sin\left(2\sqrt{x}\right)}{x}dx$$

I tried to split the interval to $\displaystyle\int _0^{\pi^2/4}\:\:\:$ and $\displaystyle\;\;\;\int _{\pi ^2/4}^{\infty }\:$

I shown convergence for the right one.

How to show convergence for the left one ? I got until the part where I showed that:

$$\frac{\left(\left(x^{1/4}+1\right)\cdot \sin \left(2\sqrt{x}\right)\right)}{x}\le \frac{\left(\left(x^{1/4}+1\right)\right)}{x}\;\;\;\;,\;\;\forall x\:\in \left(0,\:\frac{\pi \:^2}{4}\right]$$

Comment: $\sin(2 \sqrt{x}) \approx 2 \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @T.Bongers How did you know this ? so I could learn from this. I mean for the interval where $0\le \:x\le \:\frac{\pi ^2}{4}$

Comment: For small $x$, $|\sin(2\sqrt{x})| \leq 2\sqrt{x}$ so the whole thing is bounded by $2x^{-1/2}$ which has an integrable singularity.

Comment: For large $x$, you have a decay at a rate which is probably not absolutely integrable, but you have changes of sign that could give convergence anyway (in the sense of improper Riemann integration). Try splitting up the integral into regions where $\sin(2\sqrt{x})>0$ and $\sin(2\sqrt{x})<0$ and try to apply series methods.

Comment: The OP asked about convergence at $0$. I will mention, though, regarding convergence at $\infty$: a standard method to detect convergence of oscillating integrals is to integrate by parts. Here we could set $dv=\sin(2\sqrt x)/\sqrt x\,dx$ and $u=(x^{1/4}+1)/\sqrt x$; after integrating by parts, the integral converges absolutely. (The motivation: when a function oscillates, its integral will be smaller than "expected"; integration by parts detects and uses this.)

Comment: @idandi This is an application of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x }{x} = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\left(x^{1/4}+1\right)\,\sin\left(2\sqrt{x}\right)$ and split the integral in

$$J=\int _0^{\infty}f(x)\mathrm dx=\int _0^{a}f(x)\mathrm dx+\int _a^{\infty}f(x)\mathrm dx=J_1+J_2$$ for $a>0$.

For $x\to 0$ the function $f(x)\sim \frac{2\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{2}{x^{1/2}}$
and reminding that 
$$\int_0^a\frac{1}{x^{p}}\mathrm dx=\begin{cases}\frac{a^{1-p}}{1-p} &\text{for }p<1\\ +\infty & \text{for }p\ge 1\end{cases}$$
we have that $J_1$ converges because $p=\frac{1}{2}<1$.

With the substitution $u=2\sqrt x$, $\frac{1}{2}u\mathrm d u =\mathrm d x$ the integral $J_2$ becomes
$$
J_2=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_b^t \frac{2}{u}\left((u/2)^{1/2}+1\right)\,\sin u \,\mathrm d u
$$
where $b=2\sqrt a$. Integrating by parts
$$J_2=\lim_{t\to\infty} \left[\frac{2}{u}\left((u/2)^{1/2}+1\right)\,\cos u\right]_b^t-\frac{1}{2}\int_b^\infty \frac{1}{u^2}\left((2u)^{1/2}+4\right)\,\cos u\,\mathrm d u$$
and observing that $\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{2}{t}\left((t/2)^{1/2}+1\right)\,\cos t=0$ we have $$\lim_{t\to\infty} \left[\frac{2}{u}\left((u/2)^{1/2}+1\right)\,\cos u\right]_1^t=-\left[\frac{2}{b}\left((b/2)^{1/2}+1\right)\,\cos b\right]=K<\infty$$
Thus
$$
J_2=K-\frac{1}{2}\int_b^\infty \frac{1}{u^2}\left((2u)^{1/2}+4\right)\,\cos u\,\mathrm d u=K-\frac{1}{2}L
$$
with $$L=\int_b^\infty \frac{1}{u^2}\left((2u)^{1/2}+4\right)\,\cos u\,\mathrm d u$$
For $u\to \infty$ the integrand function $$\frac{1}{u^2}\left((2u)^{1/2}+4\right)\,\cos u\sim \frac{\sqrt 3 u^{1/2}}{u^2}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{u^{3/2}}$$ and reminding that 
$$\int_a^\infty\frac{1}{x^{p}}\mathrm dx=\begin{cases}\frac{a^{1-p}}{1-p} &\text{for }p>1\\ +\infty & \text{for }p\le 1\end{cases}$$
we have that $L$ converges because $p=\frac{3}{2}>1$ and then $J_2$ converges.